# Searching a random Array for a specific value

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Hi I have been told to "Write code that determines if a value, say “5”,  is contained in the array from task 7(a random array) by going backwards through the array starting at the end and comparing the search value with the values in the array. After the search, if the value is found print “The value has been found” otherwise print “The value has not been found”."

I understand the creation of the random array but I am stuck on how to work backwards through it and locate the specific value.

Here is the code so far

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = rand.Next(19);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: "I am stuck on how to work backwards through it and locate the specific value." In other words, you are stuck on the entire homework problem? :) That's probably the point: to have you figure out how to solve it. Friendly advice: in the future, try to figure it out yourself for an hour or two. If you can't figure it out, then try to google around and see if Google can help you figure it out. My two cents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the loop starting from largest to smallest index.

```
 bool found = false;
 for (int i = myArray.Length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) 
     if(myArray[i] == 5)
        found = true;
 if(found)
 {

 }
 else
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To go backward just use a for loop with the iterator to `i--`.

```
for (int i = myArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i---)
{
    if(// Check if myArray[i] equals the value to find)
    {
         // If it is the case, you can get out from the for loop with break
         break;
    }
}
```

The `for` loop is splitted in 4 parts:

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
    body
```

1. The `initializer` is executed before the first iteration in the loop (here you want to start at the last index in the array : `myArray.Length - 1`)
2. The `condition` is evaluated for each iteration, if this condition is true then it goes to 3 (you want to stay in the `for` loop while `i >= 0`) otherwise it quit the `for` loop
3. The `body` is executed for each iteration that satisfy the condition
4. The `iterator` is executed (here as you want to go backward you want to decrease `i`)
5. Then it go back to 2